# Move object every few seconds using svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Draw(one time) and move objects every five seconds as shown in figures left to right. I searched but not able to find a way to draw outer lines and move objects near to it.

```
<animate xlink:href="#blue-rectangle"
         attributeName="x" 
         from="50"
         to="425" 
         dur="5s"
         begin="circ-anim.repeat(2)"
         fill="freeze" 
         id="rect-anim" />
```

ref : https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Use the *animateMotion*'s `rotate: auto` property, after setting the desired values  *circle*s `cx` and `cy` attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `animateMotion` would be a solution for a continuous motion on the path. If you need to stop the movement at intervals I would use javascript. In this book: [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491921978) you have a thorough description of how to use javascript to emulate `animateMotion`

In order to stop the rect I'n using the timestamp for the requestAnimationFrame's callback. In the next example I'm stopping the rect every 2 seconds for 1 second.

Since the timestamp is running continuously I need a way to record the moment when it stops so that I can resume the animation from here. For this I'm setting `lastTime` as the last time when the rect has stopped.

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
let rid;//the request animation frame id
let track = document.getElementById("track"),
  trackLength = track.getTotalLength(),//the total length of the track
  dur = 15000; //duration of one loop of track, in ms
 
let lastTime = 0;//last time when the rect has stopped
let flag = false; 

let interval = 5000;


function update(time) {
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    // to stop the rect every 5 seconds
    var deltaT = time%interval;
    //during 1 second
    if (deltaT < interval/2){
    flag = false;
  var t = ((deltaT + lastTime) % dur) / dur, // position in repeat cycle
    distance, // distance along the path for this rect
    point, // SVGPoint for that distance
    point2; // SVGPoint for a slightly different distance

  distance = trackLength * (t % 1);
  point = track.getPointAtLength(distance);
  point2 = track.getPointAtLength((distance + 2) % trackLength);
  angle = Math.atan2(point.y - point2.y, point.x - point2.x);

  rect.setAttribute(
    "transform",
    "translate(" +
      [point.x, point.y] +
      ")" +
      "rotate(" +
      angle * 180 / Math.PI +
      ")"
  );

 }else{if(flag==false){lastTime += interval/2; flag = true;}}
  
}
rid = requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 150 200" width="200">
  <path id="track" d="M70,30 Q70,20 80,20L120,20 Q130,20 130,30L130,170.000 Q130,180 120,180L30,180 Q20,180 20,170L20,130 Q20,120 30,120L60,120 Q70,120 70,110Z" />
 <polygon id="rect" points="0,0 -10,0 -10,-10 0,-10 0,0" style="fill: #ff0000;"/> 
</svg>
```

## UPDATE

And this is how I would do it using `animateMotion`

```js
setInterval(()=>{ svg.pauseAnimations(); 
                  setTimeout(()=>{svg.unpauseAnimations()},1000)
                },2000);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox = "0 0 150 200" width="300">
  <path id="track" d="M70,30 Q70,20 80,20L120,20 Q130,20 130,30L130,170.000 Q130,180 120,180L30,180 Q20,180 20,170L20,130 Q20,120 30,120L60,120 Q70,120 70,110Z" />
  <polygon id="rect" points="0,0 10,0 10,10 0,10 0,0" style="fill: #ff0000;">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "0s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze">
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track" />
    </animateMotion></polygon>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE 2

Here is how you move 5 blocks on the path: The only difference is the `begin` attribute for the `animateMotion`.

all the

```js
setInterval(()=>{ svg.pauseAnimations(); 
                  setTimeout(()=>{svg.unpauseAnimations()},1500)
                },3000);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox = "30 0 360 450" width="300">
<defs>
<polygon id="theRect" points="0,0 20,0 20,20 0,20 0,0" style="fill: #ff0000;" />
</defs>

  <path id="track" d="M288.938,33 Q289,12 310,12L350,12 Q371,12 371,33L371,408 Q371,429 350,429L66,429 Q45,429 45,408L45,374 Q45,353 66,353L267,353 Q288,353 288.062,332Z" />
  
  
  <use xlink:href="#theRect">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "0s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" >
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track"  />
    </animateMotion></use>
  
  <use xlink:href="#theRect">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "-.5s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" >
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track"  />
    </animateMotion></use>
  
  <use xlink:href="#theRect">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "-1s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" >
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track" />
    </animateMotion></use>
  
  
   <use xlink:href="#theRect">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "-1.5s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" >
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track"  />
    </animateMotion></use>
  
  <use xlink:href="#theRect">
  <animateMotion id="test" begin= "-2s" dur="15s" repeatCount="infinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" >
    <mpath xlink:href= "#track"  />
    </animateMotion></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: great can we display 5-6 red block instead of one?

Comment: Of coarse you can. Try it and if you can't do it ask another question. I'll be glad to help. Meanwhile please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: I have to create another thread!! but i need to display 5 different blocks as shown in image :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Meanwhile I realize  that I can do it using `animateMotion`. Please take a look. I'll think about how to display 5 different blocks ...

Comment: And now with a last update I'm animating 5 blocks on the path. Please take a look

Comment: Superb, i have accepted the answer. If you can tell how to increase the size of RED square and bottom SVG width so it has more width

Comment: To increase the size of the square you need to rewrite `theRect` points attribute. For example instead of `points="0,0 10,0 10,10 0,10 0,0` use `points="0,0 20,0 20,20 0,20 0,0`. As for the other part of the question I don't understand what is the "bottom SVG width"

Comment: as we can see the reverse L, can we increase width of horizontal area? and not vertical which looks like "I" in svg

Comment: I suppose  you already have a path. Use that one instead of the `#track` in my code.

Comment: This coordinates are complicated, have tried changing Q M L but than it changes the structure of svg (makes it out of shape).  how can i change the height of vertical line and width of horizontal line.

Comment: Can you draw it as a polygon? If so I need the `points` value and I'll change it for you.

Comment: can i share in cm ? if that's okay !

Comment: 11 cm height of "I" vertical bar (bigger line at right side), Smaller one at left 9 cm
and 
6 cm horizontal line which we can see at bottom(top) and  9 cm bottom line
in between line there is a width of 2.5cm these all things are measured as html perspective.

Comment: Please give me a polygon

Comment: I've updated the last example using the new path. Please take a look.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks enxaneta! Great, helpful answer for me